# How to attach an electronic enclosure to glass?

Tags: pcb

I'm developing a very small PCB that I'll put inside a small case that will be attached to glass, let's say for example in a car. Once you attach this to the glass, it should stay there for a long period, but should also have the ability to be detached and attached again without too much effort.

At first I considered using a sucker also known as a  [suction cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suction_cup) but this is maybe a too bulky solution, and I need something more discreet. Also the distance between the glass and the case should be minimal, and using the suction cup this distance is considerable. So do you know something that could do the job for this application?

Comment: I've only ever seen things attached with suckers.  Maybe multiple smaller suckers instead of one big one to reduce the thickness.

Comment: The term is "[suction cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suction_cup)".

Comment: If I read your answer correctly, it's about sticking a casing to the glass. Not the PCB itself. However, I fail to see how this would be electronics.SE related in that case.

Comment: @PeterJ I would tell more about the project but I'm not autorized to do it. The velcro solution looks nice. At first instace, when you attach it, it shouldn't be dettached, but we need to consider that the user must have the posibility to dettach it if needed.

Comment: Please, it's [discreet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discreet) not [discrete](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discrete).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Italy we have a transponder-based payment system called Telepass, which sticks to the windshield using Velcro. One side attachs to the glass with tape, and the other is attached to the device.

[image]

It is pretty tough, and usually lasts for years.

It seems it uses [Dual Lock by 3M](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Adhesives/Tapes/Brands/Dual-Lock-Reclosable-Fasteners/).

Comment: Looks a nice solution. Using a tough one like the one you say could do the job.

Comment: Dual Lock comes in different formulations for different surfaces, and my recollection is that to understand which one you need, a chemical engineering degree would come in handy.  It's also INSANELY EXPENSIVE stuff, but you can buy small pieces from 3M through a sample program, unless things have changed.

Comment: Same as the US ez pass

Comment: @Scott Seidman I guess that will be expensive. Here we have the 3M normal double side strip and is quite expensive too. Anyway, we need something reliable so we will have to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend something like the [3M command](http://solutions.3m.co.uk/wps/portal/3M/en_GB/EUCommand/Command/) strips, or one of the many similar products.

These are double sided adhesive strips with a core which detaches when stretched. Once in place a small non adhesive tab protrudes, when you want to remove the strip, you pull on this tab and the adhesive pulls away from both surfaces without damaging either, until the whole strip comes away and the two surfaces are no longer bonded together.

Each application requires a new strip (or set of strips), just as you would probably have to replace ordinary double sided adhesive strips, but until removed the strength of the bond is excellent and the no-damage removal allows you to use it with products you wouldn't normally be able to.

For instance, I once pulled the whole back panel off a tablet because it was attached to the passenger window of a car much more strongly than I expected. With strips like these, that damage would have been avoided.

Note that while most of the *command* range (and most similar products I've seen)  have opaque white plastic strips, 3M also do a clear version, which could work for attaching two clear glass surfaces together.

Comment: Sounds interesting too. We will consider it.

Answer (score 1):

If glue is an option:
Interior rear view mirrors are sometimes glued to the glass.

Glue the base of the mirror to your windshield and the casing to where you'd normally put your mirror. If your PCB is insensitive to magnetivity, you could glue a magnet to the windshield instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that many glues are sensitive to sunlight, especially those heavy duty glues. I once tried to mount a 3rd braking light to the rear window, but the initially hard glue became soft like rubber over time. This is one reason why the glass usually is coated by some kind of black painting where ever something is glued to it. (The same glue lasted forever for the mirror glued to the wind shield)

Answer (score 1):

You can use velcro or velcro-like attachment, but if it's a car windshield be aware that ordinary self-stick velcro tends to peel off due to the tilt of gravity and the heat, leaving a sticky residue on the glass (or the device).  You may need a high temperature version, or get a version without adhesive (eg: for sewing in) and use your own glue.

(The velcro to velcro connection is fine, it's the glue part that fails)

If you use suction cups, you might try offsetting 2 or more small ones - to the side of your enclosure rather than between the enclosure and the glass.